# How to autogenerate cURL request string from data in Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, laravel, curl, php-curl

**Request URL -** `POST - http://example.com/api/user`

**Request Body -**

```
{
    "user_id": 10,
    "name": "user name"
}
```

**Expected Output -**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/api/user' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "user_id": 10,
    "name": "user name"
}'
```

Comment: I want to auto generate cURL code like Postman does

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have 
```{
    "user_id": 10,
    "name": "user name"
}```

and from that i want to make a cURL